# JPA/Hibernate prevent merge firing select query for children

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a batch process that that updates entities in table A (entities have pregenerated ids) and inserts child entities into table B (generated ids).

Before the batch job runs table A will always be populated and table B will always be empty.

I would like a bidirectional relationship between entity A and B (useful for other batch processes), but calling entitymanager.merge on parent A results in select statements for B as well as A. This is unnecessary as B will always be a new record and is inserted separately using entitymanager.persist. This really affects the performance as there is more than one child collection (call this C) so there are unnecessary selects for B and C.

I was hoping the using only Cascade.PERSIST on child collections would prevent these selects when calling merge on A, but seems that is not the case.

Is this possible or, as I am currently doing, is the only solution to remove the @OneToMany relationships and just have  @ManyToOnes on the parent side?

Answer (score 1):

That's why you should never use `merge` if you know that you want to insert a new record. In that case, you should use the `persist` operation which will avoid the select statements.

Comment: I am unable to use persist as there may already be an existing record in table A, hence the reason for using merge in the first place. I ended up getting the hibernate session from the entitymanager and calling session.saveOrUpdate which only performs a select on the parent entity

Comment: I don't know the use case, but you could try to use persist, and if that fails run another transaction that updates.